# calling ajax function from knockout value undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have a view model in knockout as follow. What i intend to achieve here is to make the ajax call into a reusable function as follow (and include it into separate js file).

However, I got the error message showing self.CountryList is not defined. How could this be resolved?

```
// Working
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.CountryList = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.LoadCountry = function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/MyApi',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success(data): {
          $.each(data, function (index, value) {
              self.CountryList.push(value);
          });
      }
    });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new LoadCountry());

// Not working
function LoadCountryList() {
  $.ajax({
      url: '/api/MyApi',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success(data): {
          $.each(data, function (index, value) {
              self.CountryList.push(value);
          });
      }
    });
}

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.CountryList = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.LoadCountry = function() {
     LoadCountryList();
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new LoadCountry());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well clearly `self.ContryList` does not exist in your external file. One easy way to solve this is to pass in a reference to the appropriate "list" to push values to:

```
function LoadCountryList(countryList) {
  $.ajax({
      url: '/api/MyApi',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success(data): {
          $.each(data, function (index, value) {
              countryList.push(value);
          });
      }
    });
}
```

and in your view model:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.CountryList = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.LoadCountry = function() {
     LoadCountryList(self.CountryList);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `LoadCountryList` function in the second version has no concept of the object it should be operating on - ie it has no idea what `self` is, hence the error.  The simple solution is for you to pass the object in when calling the function:

```
function LoadCountryList(vm) {
  $.ajax({
      url: '/api/MyApi',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success(data): {
          $.each(data, function (index, value) {
              //reference the parameter passed to the function
              vm.CountryList.push(value);
          });
      }
    });
}

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.CountryList = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.LoadCountry = function() {
     //pass ourselves to the function
     LoadCountryList(self);
  }
}
```